# PDO exec don't want to work with vars

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What I'm doing wrong here? I thought maybe there is a problem with variables in exec but I have a simular command working in another place. The commented part returns int(1) as effected row, and this code gives me back the following error. Thanks a lot in your advises I'm just learning.

```
"object(PDO)#2 (0) { } Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'try, Wed, 06 Mar 2013 13:25:09 +0200)' at line 1 ) "
```

code :

```
<?php
class gbMsg {
    private $_db;
    private $dbc;

    function __construct(){
        $this->dbc = parse_ini_file($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/lock/conect.ini");
        try{
            $this->_db = new PDO($this->dbc["conn"], $this->dbc["user"], $this->dbc["pass"]);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    function addPost($name, $msg){
        echo var_dump($this->_db);
        $d = date("r");
        $stmt = $this->_db->exec("INSERT INTO gPosts (name, message, date) VALUES ($name,$msg, now())")
        or die(print_r($this->_db->errorInfo(), true));
        echo var_dump($stmt);
    }
}

#   function addPost(){
#       echo var_dump($this->_db);
#       $stmt = $this->_db->exec("INSERT INTO gPosts (name, message, date) VALUES ('Kirill','sec', now())");
#       echo var_dump($stmt);
#   }
#}
```

Comment: pdo in mysql_* style you can use parameterized query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User parameterized queries is better, however, to fix your problem:

```
 $stmt = $this->_db->exec("INSERT INTO gPosts (name, message, date)
 VALUES (\"$name\",\"$msg\", now())")
```

You forgot the quotes...

You can read more about parameterized queries and prepared statements here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score -1):

I guess something like below should also work. IMHO it looks a lot more clean than escaping double quotes

```
$stmt = $this->_db->exec("INSERT INTO gPosts (name, message, date)
 VALUES ('$name','$msg', now())")
```

Comment: This adds nothing to the question or the answer. You just changed double quotes for single ones.

Comment: I guess the error was due to malformed query string. And using escaped double quotes seemed a little messy to me. Tot I'd share a cleaner way of doing it using a combination of single quotes within double quotes.